# Inserting DropDownList value to table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, parameters

I have a database table with two int columns: GameID and GenreID where GameID is the identity column. I want to insert the SelectedValue from my DropDownList into the table as GenreID using ASP.NET and C#. All my ListItems in the DropDownList look something like this:

```
<asp:ListItem Text="Action" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
```

So, here's what I'm trying to do.

Converting the DropDownList value to int:

```
int GenreID = Int32.Parse(DropDownGenre.SelectedValue);
```

The SQL command:

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT into Games_Genres values(@GenreID)");
```

And adding that value to the parameter:

```
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GenreID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = GenreID;
```

This gives me the following error:

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated.

I understand that this error usually (always?) means that the field isn't big enough to hold the data I'm trying to insert. However, seeing that I converted the value to int I don't get why that is a problem?

Comment: Did you confirm that GenreID is defined as an int in the actual database?

Comment: share the table schema

Comment: Is GenreID the first column in the schema? You do not specify a column in the SQL command

Comment: Yeah it's an int:
http://i.imgur.com/Ct1pEvg.png

Comment: this is composite primary key, did you insert gameid also or identity key?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

`cmd2.Parameters.Add("@GenreID", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd2.Parameters["@GenreID"].Value = GenreID;`

Instead?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = 
      new SqlCommand("INSERT into Games_Genres (GenreID) values(@GenreID)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Is GenreID also set as an identity column?

Also, when creating parameters for a query you don't need to specify the type because [T-SQL implicitly converts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx) types. It should look like:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT into Games_Genres (GenreID) values (@GenreID)"))
{
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GenreID", GenreID);
    cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't add comments yet so, your schema image shows GameId its a key field and you aren't setting it, if you are doint it with parameters might as well create a stored procedure instead a text query, if its only for test purposes why not try:

```
var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(String.Format("INSERT into Games_Genres values({0})", genreId));
```